# Cannot populate nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I know that this has been asked a million times, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  I cannot find a way to populate the references in an object when getting it from the database.  No matter what I try it either returns an empty list or just the list of id's.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
displayInventory: (req, res)=>{
    Merchant.find({otherId: merchantId})
        .populate({
            path: "ingredients", 
            populate: {
                path: "ingredient", 
                model: "Ingredient"
            }
        })
        .then((merchant)=>{
            console.log(merchant);
            if(merchant){
                return res.render("./inventory/inventory", {merchant: merchant});
            }else{
                return res.redirect("/merchant/new");
            }
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
            return res.render("error");
        });
}

const MerchantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    otherId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastUpdatedTime: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    ingredients: [{
        ingredient: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Ingredient"
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            min: [0, "Quantity cannot be less than 0"]
        }
    }],
    recipes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Recipe"
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to your schema, look like you just need to do:

```
Merchant.find({cloverId: merchantId}).populate("ingredients.ingredient")...
```

Comment: When I do this it is just giving me the actual id, like this:

Comment: inventory:
   [ { _id: 5d97508e7929f31fb64a3196, quantity: 123 }, ...

Comment: What is inventory? I don't see it in your schema.

Comment: Inventory is the ejs page being rendered.  However, I figured out my problem.  Refactored and messed some things up in the database.  Got it straightened out and this way of doing populate works perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```
Merchant.find({otherId: merchantId})
  .populate({ path: 'ingredients' })
  .exec(function(err, docs) {

    var options = {
      path: 'ingredients.components',
      model: 'Ingredient'
    };

    if (err) return res.json(500);
    Merchant.populate(docs, options, function (err, merchant) {
      res.json(merchant);
    });
  });
```

Comment: When I add this I just get an error about Project not being defined.  I don't really understand what this code is doing so I am not sure how to edit it for my needs...

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question in case others have a similar problem.  My problem was that I renamed some variables but forgot to do it when saving data to the database.  Stupid mistake, but just a reminder to be careful when refactoring.  I used Coung Le Ngoc's answer, it works perfectly.